# Is there any way to stop app for desire period?

Tags: android

In android is there any way to stop specific app. Let suppose i want to stop the whatsapp so is there any possibility? I have tried Force Stop method but it does not works. Whatsapp automatically turn on after sometime.

Answer (score 0):

Whatsapp like apps must have internal timers on the background service to restart it's services. So it invokes itself sometime later. Try to stop another basic app like calculator.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do programatically then you have to get permission for **Administrative**. And then your app will be able to kill other Apps. Like Greenify.

If you want to kill applications -> Use **Greenify** -> Auto Hibernate options. It will automatically hibernate applications after certain period of time.

Third way is **root** your phone and edit the permission of application. -> Remove permission of Boot to Turn on flag.